# In Elasticsearch, is there a way to get hits.total.value for each query in a compound query?

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have a compound query like the example below, would it be possible to get the total hits value per query instead of just the `hits.total.value` for the entire query as a whole?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "johann sebastian bach"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "name": "johann sebastian bach"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "johann sebastian bach",
              "minimum_should_match": "2<75%"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with a single query, but since your query is simple you could send each separately to [the `_msearch` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) and get the count for each.

```
POST your-index/_msearch
{ }
{"query" : {"match" : { "name": "johann sebastian bach"}}}
{ }
{"query" : {"match" : { "name": "johann sebastian bach"}}}
{ }
{"query" : {"match" : { "name": {"query": "johann sebastian bach", "minimum_should_match": "2<75%"}}}}
```

In the response, you'll get `hits.total.value` for each query.

Comment: That's interesting, I figured I'd have to do that however I didn't know about _msearch. What about Bucket aggregations? It says they divide matching documents into one or more containers and then gives you the number of documents in each bucket. Is that worth a shot or am I understanding it incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, you can try it with aggregations as well, each query is completely independent from each other